# "Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfException: 'Blink files are missing at /root/.nuget" Error in syncfusion HtmlToPdf convertor in docker-compose

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, docker-compose, syncfusion, html-to-pdf

I have a .net project, which runs in docker-compose.

So that I'm using  `Syncfusion.HtmlToPdfConverter.Net.Linux`for the .net core application.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Syncfusion.HtmlConverter;
using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Catalog.Api.Controllers.V5
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("v5/pdf-generate")]
    public class PdfGenerateController : Controller
    {
        public PdfGenerateController(){}

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult UrlToPdf()
        {
                //Initialize HTML to PDF converter.
                HtmlToPdfConverter htmlConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

                //Convert URL to PDF document.
                PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert("https://www.google.com");

                //Create memory stream.
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                //Save and close the document.
                document.Save(stream);
                document.Close(true);

                return File(stream.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "HTML-to-PDF.pdf");          
        }
    }
}
```

this is my controller.

I run this controller and got the error.

```
Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfException: 'Blink files are missing at /root/.nuget/packages/syncfusion.htmltopdfconverter.net.linux/21.2.9/lib/netstandard2.0/runtimes/linux/native'
```

PLEASE ANYONE HELP ME?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and after adding the following on the Dockerfile:

```bash
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \ 
    libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \ 
    libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \ 
    libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 \ 
    libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \ 
    libnss3 libgbm1
```

And adding the `BlinkConverterSettings` as given on the sample source code above:

```cs
    BlinkConverterSettings settings = new BlinkConverterSettings();
    settings.CommandLineArguments.Add("--no-sandbox");
    settings.CommandLineArguments.Add("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
    //Convert URL to PDF document.
    htmlConverter.ConverterSettings = settings;
```

It worked perfectly.